# swift4 Firebaseへのデータの登録が上手くいかない

Tags: swift4

```
var dbReference: DatabaseReference?
var dbHandle: DatabaseHandle?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     dbReference = Database.database().reference()
     dbReference?.child("name").childByAutoId().setValue("Yash")
     dbReference?.child("name").childByAutoId().setValue("Rahul")

     // retrive data
     dbHandle = dbReference?.child("name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
         let name:String? = snapshot.value as? String
         print(name as Any)
     })
```

YouTube 上ではこの記述で  "Yash" と "Rahul" が Firebase 上に作成されたのですが、私のテストでは上手くいきません。

Firebase 上の URL をセットしなくても良いのでしょうか?
またはどこでセットしたら良いか教えて戴けませんか?

Comment: youtube上とはyoutubeにアップしている人のことで私ではありません。

Comment: google-infoを書き直していたら上手くいきました。

Comment: 解決しているならご自身で回答を記入してください